# Using rlang Package to Parse Quoted Argument

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang

I'm hoping to string-split a single argument into two arguments and use each in different sections of a function.

Is it possible to do this using quasiquotation (`!!`) or other rlang functions?

Thanks!

**Data:**

```
person <- tibble(id = 1, age = 20)
friends <- tibble(id = c(2, 3, 4, 5), age = c(48, 29, 20, 48))
```

**(unfunctional) Function:**

```
different_age_friends <- function(condition, person = person, friends = friends ) {

  person <- person
  friends <- friends

  condition <- str_split(condition, " ~ ", simplify = T)
  condition_statement <- condition[1]
  filter_statement <- condition[2]

  if(!!condition_statement) {
    different_age_friends <- friends %>%
      filter(!!filter_statement)
  }

  return(return_same_age_friends)
}
```

**Call:**

```
different_age_friends(condition = "age == 20 ~ age == 48")
```

**Desired Output**

```
id age
2  48
5  48
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue, but you've got `condition = TRUE` where you want `condition == TRUE`, or just `condition`, to do a comparison

Comment: Also, I'm unclear on the difference between the condition and the filter. I don't get what's substantially different between these two types of statements. Are you trying to test the condition against `person`, and then if true, use the second piece to filter `friends`?

Comment: yes exactly, thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rlang::parse_expr` to convert strings to expressions and `eval` to evaluate them. `eval()` allows you to provide context for the expression in its second argument, where we supply the `person` data frame to it. In case of `filter`, the context is already understood to be the dataframe on the left-hand side of the `%>%` pipe.

Another difference in how we handle the two expressions is that `filter()` has an additional internal layer of [quasiquoation](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quasiquotation.html). Since you already have an expression, you don't need it to be quoted again, so you would use `!!` to unquote it.

```
different_age_friends <- function(condition, p = person, f = friends) 
{
  stmts <- str_split(condition, " ~ ")[[1]] %>% map( rlang::parse_expr )

  if( eval(stmts[[1]], p) )         # Effectively: eval(age == 20, person)
    f %>% filter(!!stmts[[2]])      # Effectively: friends %>% filter(age == 48)
  else
    f
}

different_age_friends(condition = "age == 20 ~ age == 48")
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#      id   age
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     2    48
# 2     5    48
```

Minor note:

- You didn't provide a value for `different_age_friends` when the condition is false. I made an assumption that in this case, the entire friends list is to be returned.